# Is $m\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-groups

Since each 'generator' of $m\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $km\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\bar{a}=k\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}m\bar{a}=k\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}0=0$.

Comment: $m\mathbb Z\simeq\mathbb Z\implies m\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No -- you can't say "$k\otimes_{\mathbb Z} m\bar a$" unless $k$ is *itself* a multiple of $m$. Otherwise it is not a member of the left factor of the tensor product.

Instead, we can note that $\mathbb Z$ and $m\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic as groups, so the tensor product ought to be the same (up to isomorphism) as $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.